# Why is this React component rendered 4 times?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

Basically I have React component that fetches Data from Firestore and stores the data in the `items` array. Afterwards I am rendering all the data in the component. My current Problem is that `menus`has 3 empty arrays and I don't know why... also they get rendered to the page.

First I had an async function to fetch the data, but I changed it to a normal function with an `unsubscribe` const. Firestore provides an `unscubscribe()` function that removes the listener when invoked. I thought maybe the `getMenu()` get's called severall times and that's why I have empty arrays, but it didn't solved my problem...

And now I am stuck with this problem, I would be thankful if anyone could help.

```
import { collection, getDocs, onSnapshot, orderBy, query } from 'firebase/firestore';
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react'
import { db, firebaseApp } from '../../firebase'

export default function Speisekarte() { 

    const [menus, setMenus] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

   console.log(menus); // line 10: gives me 3 empty arrays and one filled array in the console
   

    function getMenu(){
    
    setLoading(true)
    const docRef = query(collection(db, "meals"), orderBy("id", "asc"));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(docRef, (querySnapshot) => {
        const items = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            items.push(doc.data());
        });
        setMenus(items);
    });
    setLoading(false);
    unsubscribe();
}

useEffect(() => {
    getMenu();
},[]);

    return (
        <section className="menu">
          <div className="menu__container">
            <h1 className="menu__container__title">Menu</h1>
            {menus.map((item) => {
              const keys = Object.keys(item);
              return (
                <Fragment key={item.title}>
                        <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                        <div className="menu__container__item">
                        {keys.map((gericht) => (
                            <article className="menu__container__item-article" key={item[gericht].id}>
                                <div className="menu__container__item-article__row">
                                    <h3 className="menu__container__item-article__title">{item[gericht].title}</h3>
                                    <span className="menu__container__item-article__price">{item[gericht].price}</span>
                                </div>
                                <p className="menu__container__item-article__info">
                                    {item[gericht].desc}
                                </p>
                            </article>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                  
                </Fragment>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </section>
      );
}
```

**console log:**

```
Array [] speisekarte.js:10:12
Array [] speisekarte.js:10:12
Array [] speisekarte.js:10:12
Array [ {…}, {…} ] speisekarte.js:10:12
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthProvider } from './contexts/AuthContext';


import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Home from './pages/home'
import Speisekarte from './pages/speisekarte'
import Gallery from './pages/gallery'
import Kontakt from './pages/contact'
import Impressum from './pages/impressum';
import Signin from './pages/Signin';
import Admin from './pages/admin'

import './Sass/app.scss'




function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
       <div id="main">
        <Router>
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/gallerie" component={Gallery} />
            <Route path="/kontakt" component={Kontakt} />
            <Route path="/impressum" component={Impressum} />
            <Route path="/speisekarte" component={Speisekarte} />
            <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </Router>
      </div>
    </AuthProvider>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The `menu` does not have 3 empty arrays. It has only one at the time. The component rerenders 4 times, and for the first 3 times the value of menu is `[]`. In the 4th render there are some objects inside the menu array

Comment: okayy thanks for the hint, but why does get rendered 4 times? I added it to the app.js only once and it doesn't get imported more than once

Comment: Components rerender when their state change, or when their parent rerender. Can you show the App.js file?

Comment: BTW. I think there is something wrong with the `unsubscribe` function. Read it carefully and make sure about missing `}`

Comment: added the app.js. In the indes.js is no React.StrictMode
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen. It should be correct. I could remove the error handler, but should be fine

Answer (score 1):

React re-renders its components every time any of its state changes.
In the above first the state of loading changes and at that moment the menu is still empty so it is logging an empty array.

But after the array has been fetched from the firestore. React again re-renders the component and it logs the fetched array which is stored in the menus. 
That is why it is console logging every time any of the states changes.

Comment: And how would I stop it from doing that?

Comment: you can log it inside useEffect hook it will only run when the component updates. In the code, there are two useEffects doing the same thing

Comment: sorry but I am quite new to react. If I ad the ```console.log(menus)``` in the useEffect Hook. I get an empty array. And where is the other useEffect Hook?

Comment: ohhh I saw it. I am really sorry, that was my mistake. there is actually only one useEffect Hook. But still, the problem exists

Comment: It takes time to fetch data from the server until the data is fetched the menus array is empty and because of change in state, it is re-rendering the component and running the log command, and logging an empty array after the data has been fetched it will log the fetched data and update the state which will again fire a re-render and will log the fetched data in the menus array.